# Using constructor of an object within another class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I created a class with a constructor that takes an int to determine the size of a linked list the object has. The problem I'm having is I need to be able to call this constructor when this object is instantiated as a private member of another class. So basically:

```
class A {
public:
    A();
    A(int size);
};

class B {
    const int size = // any number > 0
private:
    A a(size);
};
```

I get this error:

> constant "B::size" is not a type name

I've tried searching online, but I can't come across this specific issue. It could be that I'm struggling to word the question correctly... it's a weird issue I haven't seen yet. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You have declared methods but you have not implemented them. Where's the implementation?

Comment: That's a faulty design. I suggest you ask about the actual problem you are trying to solve, and not about the solution you had in mind.

Comment: The constructor for A should be called in the constructor for B. You can't instantiate directly in a header file unless you are using a constant.

Comment: Your declaration of `A a(size);` is wrong, should be `A a;` and initialize the `a` member in class `B`'s constructor member initialization list.

Comment: Thanks donutmonger and πάντα ῥεῖ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot call the constructor with parameters in the member variable declaration.

You can implement a constructor for B and do it there.

```
B::B() : a(size) {}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for. I have no idea why I didn't try that...

Answer (score 2):

You have to do in the `B` constructor, using an [*initializer list*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class B
{
public:
    B() : a(size)
    {}

private:
    A a;
    const int size = ...;
};
```